# How Do I graph from a List in Livecharts

Tags: c#, wpf, linechart, livecharts

I have been trying to learn how to use Live charts for a School project where I need to be able to graph Large amounts of data. My code gets the data from a file and puts it into a linked list(points) where it is then copied into the Chartvalues Data Structure. using a resource dictionary I have filled the area under the line with white so I could test whether it graphed or not

```
using LiveCharts.Wpf;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using LiveCharts;
using LiveCharts.Defaults;
using LiveCharts.Helpers;

namespace Flux_calibrator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        LList<spec> points = new LList<spec>();
        LList<spec> pointr = new LList<spec>();
        OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
        SaveFileDialog sav = new SaveFileDialog();
        ChartValues<ObservablePoint> specg = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>();
        ChartValues<ObservablePoint> refg = new ChartValues<ObservablePoint>();
        int caseswitch = 0;
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SeriesCollection SeriesCollection = new SeriesCollection
            {
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Title="Spectrum",
                    Values = specg,
                },
                new LineSeries
                {
                    Title="Refrence",
                    Values = refg,
                }
            };
        }

        private void Opr_Click(object senderl, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Sas_Click(object senderl, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] f = new string[points.Length];
            sav.Filter = "Dat|*.dat";
            sav.ShowDialog();
            string path = sav.FileName;
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(path))
            {
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                var save = File.Create(path);
                int Length = points.Length;
                for (int i = 0; i < Length; i++)
                {
                    spec w = points.pop();
                    f[i] = Math.Round(w.WL, 6).ToString() + "       " + w.IT.ToString();
                }
                save.Close();
                File.WriteAllLines(path, f, Encoding.UTF8);
            }
        }

        private void Sar_Click(object senderl, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void col_Click(object senderl, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            System.Windows.Application.Current.Shutdown();
        }

        private void fluxcal(LList<spec> spectrum, double zerop, double effective, double wavestep, double Counts, double mag)
        {
            double pow = (mag) * -1 / 2.5;
            double F = zerop * Math.Pow(10, pow);
            double max = effective + wavestep;
            double min = effective - wavestep;
            double count = Counts * (wavestep / (max - min));
            double scale = F / count;
            double distance = 1800000;
            int i = 0;
            while (Math.Abs(spectrum.getById(i).WL - effective) <= distance)
            {
                distance = Math.Abs(spectrum.getById(i).WL - effective);
                i++;
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < spectrum.Length; j++)
            {
                spectrum.getById(j).IT *= scale;
            }
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            double mag;
            switch (caseswitch)
            {
                case 0:
                    MessageBox.Show("Please open a spectrum");
                    break;
                case 1:
                    if (!double.TryParse(MagT.Text, out mag))
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please ensure that all inputs are numbers");
                    }
                    else if (VBand.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        fluxcal(points, 363.1 * Math.Pow(10, -11), 5450, 850, findcounts(points, 5450, 850), mag);
                    }
                    else if (UBand.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        fluxcal(points, 417.5 * Math.Pow(10, -11), 3600, 60, findcounts(points, 3600, 600), mag);
                    }
                    else if (BBand.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        fluxcal(points, 632 * Math.Pow(10, -11), 4380, 90, findcounts(points, 4380, 900), mag);
                    }
                    else if (RBand.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        fluxcal(points, 217.7 * Math.Pow(10, -11), 6410, 1500, findcounts(points, 6410, 1500), mag);
                    }
                    else if (IBand.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        fluxcal(points, 112.6 * Math.Pow(10, -11), 7980, 1500, findcounts(points, 7980, 1500), mag);
                    }
                    else if (JBand.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        fluxcal(points, 31.47 * Math.Pow(10, -11), 12000, 2600, findcounts(points, 12200, 2600), mag);
                    }
                    else if (HBand.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        fluxcal(points, 11.38 * Math.Pow(10, -11), 16300, 2900, findcounts(points, 16300, 2900), mag);
                    }
                    else if (KBand.IsChecked == true)
                    {
                        fluxcal(points, 3.961 * Math.Pow(10, -11), 21900, 4100, findcounts(points, 21900, 4100), mag);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("What the fuck did you do");
                    }
                    break;
            }

        }
        private double findcounts(LList<spec> spectrum, double effective, double step)
        {
            double min = effective - step;
            double max = effective + step;
            int i = 0;
            int j = 0;
            double distance = 6742376432;
            double count = 0;
            while (Math.Abs(spectrum.getById(i).WL - max) <= distance)
            {
                distance = Math.Abs(spectrum.getById(i).WL - max);
                i++;
            }
            distance = 6742376432;
            while (Math.Abs(spectrum.getById(j).WL - min) <= distance)
            {
                distance = Math.Abs(spectrum.getById(j).WL - min);
                j++;
            }
            j = j - 1;
            i = i - 1;
            while ((j) < (i))
            {
                count += spectrum.getById(j).IT;
                j++;
            }
            return count;
        }

        private void R_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void V_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void B_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void U_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void I_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void J_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void H_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void K_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void open_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ofd.Filter = "Dat|*.dat";
            Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                caseswitch = 1;
                string pathr = ofd.FileName;
                StreamReader re = new StreamReader(pathr);
                string p = re.ReadLine();
                while (p != null)
                {
                    string[] spec = p.Split('   ');
                    if (double.TryParse(spec[0], out double wv))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The file contains non double characters");
                    }
                    if (double.TryParse(spec[1], out double it))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The file contains non double characters");
                    }
                    points.addList(new spec(wv, it));
                    p = re.ReadLine();
                }
                for (int i = 0; i < points.Length; i++)
                {
                    specg.Add(new ObservablePoint(points.getById(i).WL, points.getById(i).IT));
                    /*{
                        X = points.getById(i).WL,
                        Y = points.getById(i).IT
                    });*/
                }
                
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("File could not be found");
            }

        }

        private void openr_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ofd.Filter = "Dat|*.dat";
            Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                string pathr = ofd.FileName;
                StreamReader re = new StreamReader(pathr);
                string p = re.ReadLine();
                while (p != null)
                {
                    string[] spec = p.Split('   ');
                    if (double.TryParse(spec[0], out double wv))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The file contains non double characters");
                    }
                    if (double.TryParse(spec[1], out double it))
                    {
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("The file contains non double characters");
                    }
                    pointr.addList(new spec(wv, it));
                    p = re.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and the Main window Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="Flux_calibrator.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
        xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Flux_calibrator"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="465" Width="800" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" ResizeMode="NoResize" Background="{x:Null}" AllowsTransparency="True">
    <Grid>
        <materialDesign:Card Margin="-1,0,1,0">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="72"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="44"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="materialDesign:PackIcon">
                        <Setter Property="Width" Value="30"></Setter>
                        <Setter Property="Height" Value="30"></Setter>
                    </Style>
                </Grid.Resources>
                <Grid Grid.Column="0" Background="#2C2F33">
                    <ListView Margin="0 15">
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="OpenFile">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#DC143C" Foreground="Black" Name="open" Click="open_Click" ToolTip="Open Spectrum">
                                <StackPanel Margin="-5">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="FileChart"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" Name="openrefrence">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#DC143C" Foreground="Black" Name="openr" Click="openr_Click" ToolTip="Open Spectrum">
                                <StackPanel Margin="-5">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="file"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" x:Name="Save"
                                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#DC143C" Foreground="Black" Click="Sas_Click">
                                <StackPanel Margin="-5">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ContentSave"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#DC143C" Foreground="Black">
                                <StackPanel Margin="-5">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="Division"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                                
                            </Button>
                        </ListViewItem>
                        <ListViewItem HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0 10" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <Button Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignFloatingActionButton}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="col_Click" 
                                BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Background="#DC143C" Foreground="Black">
                                <StackPanel Margin="-5">
                                    <materialDesign:PackIcon Kind="ExitToApp"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Button>
                        </ListViewItem>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
                <Grid Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,-693,0" Background="#23272A" Name="RenderPages">
                    <lvc:CartesianChart Margin="10,10,9.8,109.8" Series="{Binding SeriesCollection}">
                        
                    </lvc:CartesianChart>
                    <Grid Margin="0,355,0,0" Background="#FF3E3E42" >
                        <Label x:Name="label" Content="Flux Calibartion" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="353,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Foreground="#DDFFFFFF"/>
                        <RadioButton Margin="13,33,639,50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="U-Band" Name="UBand" Foreground="White" Background="Crimson" BorderBrush="Crimson">
                            <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0.472"/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2.992"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <Label x:Name="label_Copy" Content="Spectral Bands" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" Foreground="#DDFFFFFF"/>
                        <RadioButton Margin="13,58,639,25" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="B-Band" x:Name="BBand" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Crimson" Background="Crimson">
                            <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0.472"/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2.992"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton Margin="83,33,569,48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="V-Band" x:Name="VBand" Foreground="White" Background="Crimson" BorderBrush="Crimson" IsChecked="True">
                            <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0.472"/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2.992"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton Margin="83,58,569,25" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="R-Band" x:Name="RBand" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Crimson" Background="Crimson">
                            <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0.472"/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2.992"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton Margin="153,33,499,48" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="I-Band" x:Name="IBand" Foreground="White" Background="Crimson" BorderBrush="Crimson">
                            <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0.472"/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2.992"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton Margin="153,60,499,23" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="J-Band" x:Name="JBand" Foreground="White" BorderBrush="Crimson" Background="Crimson">
                            <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0.472"/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2.992"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton Margin="218,33
                                     ,434,45" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="H-Band" x:Name="HBand" Foreground="White" Background="Crimson" BorderBrush="Crimson">
                            <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0.472"/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2.992"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <RadioButton Margin="218,60,434,20" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Content="K-Band" x:Name="KBand" Foreground="White" Background="Crimson" BorderBrush="Crimson">
                            <RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                                <TransformGroup>
                                    <ScaleTransform/>
                                    <SkewTransform AngleY="0.472"/>
                                    <RotateTransform/>
                                    <TranslateTransform Y="2.992"/>
                                </TransformGroup>
                            </RadioButton.RenderTransform>
                        </RadioButton>
                        <TextBox x:Name="MagT" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="458,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="90" CaretBrush="White" SelectionBrush="Crimson" Foreground="White"/>
                        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Calibrate" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="40" Margin="568,35,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="115" BorderBrush="Crimson" Background="Crimson" Click="button_Click"/>
                        <Label x:Name="label1" Content="Vega Magnitude:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Margin="353,50,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Foreground="White"/>
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </Grid>
        </materialDesign:Card>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

and App.xaml

```
<Application x:Class="Flux_calibrator.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:lvc="clr-namespace:LiveCharts.Wpf;assembly=LiveCharts.Wpf"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Flux_calibrator"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Light.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignThemes.Wpf;component/Themes/MaterialDesignTheme.Defaults.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Primary/MaterialDesignColor.DeepPurple.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MaterialDesignColors;component/Themes/Recommended/Accent/MaterialDesignColor.Lime.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <Style TargetType="lvc:LineSeries">
                <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="3"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="PointGeometrySize" Value="5"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="LineSmoothness" Value="0"></Setter>
                <Setter Property="Fill" Value="White"></Setter>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And LList

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Flux_calibrator
{
    public class LList<T>
    {
        private Node<T> LastNode;
        private Node<T> FirstNode;
        public int Length;
        public LList()
        {
            Length = 0;
        }

        public void push(T Data)
        {
            this.addList(Data);
        }

        public T pop()
        {
            if (LastNode != null)
            {
                T temp = this.getById(LastNode.index);
                this.Remove(LastNode.index);
                return temp;
            }
            return default;
        }

        public void Remove(int ID)
        {
            Node<T> currentNode = FirstNode;
            Node<T> Pos = null;
            while (currentNode != null)
            {
                if (currentNode.index == ID)
                {
                    if (currentNode.previous != null)
                    {
                        currentNode.previous.setNext(ref currentNode.next);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        FirstNode = currentNode.next;
                    }
                    if (currentNode.next != null)
                    {
                        currentNode.next.setPrevious(ref currentNode.previous);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        LastNode = currentNode.previous;
                    }
                    Pos = currentNode;
                }
                else if (currentNode.index > ID)
                {
                    currentNode.index--;
                }
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
            }
            if (Pos != null)
            {
                Pos.next = null;
                Pos.previous = null;
                Length--;
            }
        }

        public void addList(T Data)
        {
            Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(Data, Length);
            if (FirstNode == null)
            {
                FirstNode = newNode;
            }
            if (LastNode != null)
            {
                LastNode.setNext(ref newNode);
                newNode.setPrevious(ref LastNode);
            }
            LastNode = newNode;
            Length++;
        }
        public T getById(int ID)
        {
            if (ID > Length / 2)
            {
                Node<T> currentNode = LastNode;
                Node<T> Pos = null;
                while (currentNode != null)
                {
                    if (currentNode.index == ID)
                    {
                        Pos = currentNode;
                    }
                    currentNode = currentNode.previous;
                }
                if (Pos != null)
                {
                    return Pos.data;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Node<T> currentNode = FirstNode;
                Node<T> Pos = null;
                while (currentNode != null)
                {
                    if (currentNode.index == ID)
                    {
                        Pos = currentNode;
                    }
                    currentNode = currentNode.next;
                }
                if (Pos != null)
                {
                    return Pos.data;
                }
            }
            return default(T);
        }
    }
    class Node<T>
    {
        public T data;
        public Node<T> next;
        public Node<T> previous;
        public int index;
        public Node(T Data, int Index)
        {
            data = Data;
            index = Index;
        }
        public Node(T Data, ref Node<T> Next, int Index)
        {
            data = Data;
            next = Next;
            index = Index;
        }
        public Node(T Data, ref Node<T> Next)
        {
            data = Data;
            next = Next;
        }
        public Node(T Data)
        {
            data = Data;

        }
        public void setNext(ref Node<T> Next)
        {
            next = Next;
        }
        public void setPrevious(ref Node<T> Prev)
        {
            previous = Prev;
        }
    }
}
```

and spec.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Flux_calibrator
{
    public class spec
    {
        private double wl;
        private double it;

        public double WL
        {
            get { return wl; }
        }
        public double IT
        {
            get
            {
                return it;
            }
            set
            {
                it = value;
            }
        }
        public spec(double wl, double it)
        {
            this.it = it;
            this.wl = wl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. your question needs some more explanation so someone can help better, especially how much of these codes are your own writing, how much of it are part of a tutorial, what have tried so far before you came for help, what errors you have etc.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Does this [answer helps](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63207357/3141792)? You need to modify `StartSineGenerator()` to report the values you retrieved from the file.